# Is Go able to be used for the BotFramework SDK or does it require porting?

Tags: go, botframework

I'm in need of using the BotFramework SDK to build a bridge from Skype to Mattermost. As I understand it, we're pretty much limited to using the BotFramework to accomplish this via their SDK, however C# and Node.js are not really an option for this presently in this case.  Is there a way to use Go already with the SDK or does some porting need to be done?

Comment: You could just use the REST API.

Comment: That's a good call. While discussing this with others it appears we missed the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference

Comment: There unfortunately is not a BotBuilder SDK for Go at this time. As Michael indicated, you can use the REST API to use the Bot Framework. Just to illustrate that it's possible, there is a 3rd party Ruby port [here](https://github.com/tachyons/botframework-ruby). Also, if you'd like, you can leave feedback on [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1214) to indicate your interest in BotBuilder support for Go.

Comment: @StevenG, thanks. Given your position and understanding, could you please chime in here: https://github.com/42wim/matterbridge/issues/470

Answer (score 0):

As for January 2020 an implemntation has been provided (not officialy by MS):

https://www.infracloud.io/microsoft-bot-framwework-sdk-for-go/